# Crop image using Thumbnailator starting at x,y and size of height,width

Tags: java, thumbnails, java-2d

I need to crop an image starting at position x,y and it should be height,width in size (starting at x,y). I have the following code:

```
Thumbnails
        .of(url)
        .size(width, height)
        .crop(new Coordinate(x,y))
        .toOutputStream(os);
        ;
```

But it does not seem to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: Define "not working". Is there an exception? Nothing is happening and the image is not cropped?

Comment: May try to change ".crop(new Coordinate(x,y))" and ".size(width, height)" place?

Comment: No issue: something gets cropped but not at the right place. Sometimes works if I try at the x,y which are small. I tried switching the order but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Thumbnails
    .of(url)
    .scale(1)
    .sourceRegion(x, y, width, height)
    .toOutputStream(os);
```

did the trick! Too bad the library's documentation is so lacking. It is a very nice one.